# how do I dump the attribute route tables in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to find an attribute routing problem in MVC5. Since the page isn't loading (404) the tools out there for finding routes can't help. If I can get a dump of the routing tables I could at least figure out what it thinks its looking for.

Does anyone have code that does this that they could share?

thanks,

john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/).

> This utility displays the route data pulled from the request of the
>   current request in the address bar. So you can type in various URLs in
>   the address bar to see which route matches. At the bottom, it shows a
>   list of all defined routes in your application. This allows you to see
>   which of your routes would match the current URL.

Comment: This is helpful, for some reason its not adding the routes I want, but that's a separate question. Thank you.